# Pandas, read_sql() - reading from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am reading data into pandas from a SQL Server database.

I am using Python 2.7.

I want to output the resulting query data into dataframe.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\my_server;Database=my_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
sql = "select * from my_table"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

However, this fails with the error message :

> Ascii codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position. ordinal not in range(128)

What do I need to do to successfully export it into a dataframe?

Comment: This says you tried to read Unicode data as if it was ASCII. This isn't a SQL Server error, nor is it something affected by the connection string

Comment: BTW why are you using Python 2.7? That's the reason for this error - Python 2 tries to convert Unicode to ASCII. The real fix would be to use Python 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASCII codec can't encode character u'\u2013'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039212/ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2013)